# ontouchstart on a button open a drop down list

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a dropdown list when a touchevent start on a button.

This one doesn't bring the select options. Any solutions please?

```
function mouseDown(){
var game=[game1,game2];
var html='<select>';
for(i=0;i<game.length;i++)
{
html+='<option>'+game[i]+'</option>';
}
html+='</select>';
$("#button").append(html);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to get the solution.

1. I added the image as a background to the drop down list,set the
   `data-role` to none, removed the border etc.. refer to css in the
   fiddle
2. To avoid preselected text from the drop down list I got the solution
   from one of the discussion in stack overflow, but forgot to get the
   url, so couldn't print it here-apologize.  Solution is to set the
   selectedIndex to -1. Refer to the function in the fiddle. Call the
   function from the body tag. Idea is to reset the page on each load
   so the selected value will no longer be present.
3. To avoid showing the text on the background image, I added a
   text-intent to -9999px so the text wont show on the image. I got
   this solution again from a different discussion within this  site.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JpnK4/)

Have fun and enjoy your day... Happy learning...

Answer (score 0):

If `game1` and `game2` aren't variable then this is the issue.

```
var game=["game1","game2"];  //MISSED the ""
```

Try like this

```
var game = ["game1", "game2"];
var html = $("<select/>");
for (var val in game) {
    $("<option />", {
        value: val,
        text: game[val]
    }).appendTo(html);
}
html.appendTo($('button'));
```

Comment: missing ""  was a typo, i have used it in the code thought. I am getting the dropdown list, since i am using jquery it is showing with a down arrow button and a pre selected game:game1 and game1 is displayed on the button. anyway to ignore it from displaying?

Comment: @user2706195 You mean a default value (html+='<option></option>';) like this http://jsfiddle.net/zYSYJ/2/

Comment: In the fiddle, select option is visible on the button. Is it possible to display just the button? selectoption should popup only when an action is performed on the button. Select options text should not be displayed on the button. Idea is, on selecting game1, i will redirect to another page.

Comment: List is on the side. Also button name-button is getting replaced with game1 as soon as i select it. button should be maintainer as button. on selecting game1, I will redirect to another page